# Android. Use service or application class for locationListener

Tags: android, service, location

I have a task to determine user location. I can create LocationListener in Application class. Or I can use Service.

```
LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  LocationListener locationListener=new LocationListener(){
public void onLocationChanged(    Location location){
  dive.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
  dive.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
  mapHelper.setMapPosition(dive.getLatitude(),dive.getLongitude());
}
public void onStatusChanged(    String provider,    int status,    Bundle extras){
}
public void onProviderEnabled(    String provider){
}
public void onProviderDisabled(    String provider){
}};
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
```

What do I need to use for this task? Service or application class? What are the advantages and disadvantages of the service? What are the advantages and disadvantages of the application class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd never, ever use the application.  You might use the Activity.  Using the Activity is more convenient, but can't persist to the next activity.  Service requires extra boilerplate and less ease of access to the data, but it can be used for multiple activities that need the data.

Comment: "You'd never, ever use the application" - Why?

Comment: Because you shouldn't be using it for anything.  It's kind of a dead idea in Android.  At one point people used it for holding statics (singletons and the like), but its a pain in the neck to subclass (you have to remember to override it in the manifest) and really provides no benefits over doing it elsewhere.  Right now its really only used for 1 or 2 system calls like onLowMemory that almost nobody overrides.  It's kind of like your appendix-  it once had a purpose, but not anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If your application needs to obtain real-time location information, both can be used.

```
MyApplication extends Application implements locationListener
MyService extends Service implements locationListener
```

Because the application's life cycle is the longest, so you can use the application in the service.You only need to concern about how to pass the acquired data to the Activity(interface，broadcast...).